# Split up answers when converting to comments

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, answers, convert-to-comment, answer-length

Currently, answers get cut off at the comment limit when converting.  Can we get answers split into at least two comments?  I think it would cover about 99% of answers, only losing content on 1%.

Comment: How often are you running into answers with 600+ characters that are worth converting into multiple comments?

Comment: @GraceNote: maybe 5-8% of the time.  Not exactly a 3 alarm fire, but one that would be nice to have.  It would cover just about every answer you'd convert except for ones whose length makes it pointless.

Comment: As a workaround, you can convert it to comment twice and then edit the comments into shape.

Comment: @mmyers: to comment - undelete - edit - to comment.  Ick.

Comment: Last time I tried, I didn't have to undelete before converting again, but looks like that's no longer possible.

Answer (score 1):

Er.. why would we encourage splitting "long" text into comments when we have a 600 character limit *specifically for that reason*?

I say if it can't fit in 600 characters, them's the breaks. Be more concise, or next time, post an actual answer that doesn't need to be forced into the comment format.

Comment: Maybe add a warning if the length is > 600 before converting?